# Given $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous at $x_0$ and $f(x_0) > 0 \Rightarrow \exists r > 0: f(x) > 0 \ \forall x \in B_r(x_0)$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Given $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous at $x_0$ and $f(x_0) > 0$, I am trying to show that there exists $r > 0: f(x) > 0 \ \forall x \in B_r(x_0)$.

Since $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ we know that given $\epsilon > 0, \exists \ r>0 : x \in B_r(x_0) \Rightarrow f(x) \in B_\epsilon(f(x_0)).$

We know that $f(x) > f(x_0) - \epsilon > -\epsilon \ $. But how can we make $f(x) > 0$?

Comment: Take a sufficiently small $\epsilon$ for which $f(x_0)-\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Yes, $0 < \epsilon < f(x_0)$, but would that be the value of $r$ I am looking for? @Mark

Comment: I think you might be confusing yourself a bit with notation - to tweak your second line suggestively, "Since $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, we know that given $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists r > 0$ such that $x \in B_r(x_0) \implies f(x) \in B_{\epsilon}(f(x_0))$". Does that help?

Comment: If I choose the value of $\epsilon$ such that $0 < \epsilon < f(x_0)$ then $f(x) > 0 \ \forall x  \ \in B_\epsilon(f(x_0))$. Would that imply that $f(x) > 0 \ \forall x \ \in B_r(x_0)$?.

Comment: yes, with that choice of $\epsilon$, the associated $r$ will have the desired property! (using the triangle inequality, to be precise)

Comment: be careful with your notation however - specifically, the line in your comment "$f(x) > 0 \ \forall x \in B_{\epsilon}(f(x_0))$ doesn't work. If $x \in B_{\epsilon}(f(x_0))$, then in particular $x \in \mathbb{R}$, so it doesn't make sense to talk about $f(x)$. But it would be accurate to say that for $0 < \epsilon < f(x_0)$, then $y > 0 \ \forall y \in B_{\epsilon}(f(x_0))$. I think this is what you meant.

Comment: Right. If I said $f(x) > 0 \ \forall f(x) \ \in B_\epsilon(f(x_0))$ instead. Would it be correct then?

Comment: @JonathanPal how can we make use of the triangle inequality here? I can't see it.

Comment: I think he meant you can use $d(f(x),0) \leq d(f(x), f(x_0)) + d(f(x_0),0)$ @peter fizza

Comment: @peterfizza my apologies, I misspoke. what I meant to say was that $y \in B_{\epsilon}(f(x_0))$ implies $|f(x_0) - y| < \epsilon$ implies $y > f(x_0) - \epsilon > 0$. This doesn't actually use the triangle inequality. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Indeed. But does this show $y > 0 \ \forall x \in B_r(x_0)$? @JonathanPal

Comment: yes, given that we choose $r$ to be such that $f(x) \in B_{\epsilon}(f(x_0))$ for all $x \in B_r (x_0)$, then we have that $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in B_r (x_0)$. @peterfizza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take any $0 < \epsilon < f(x_0)$ as it was suggested.

We have that given $x \in B_r(x_0) \Rightarrow f(x) \in B_\epsilon(f(x_0)) \Rightarrow f(x) > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Choose specific value of $\varepsilon$ for example $\frac{f(x_0)}2$.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to show this is by contradiction. If you assume that there is no $r>0$ $f(x)>0 ~~\forall x\in B_r(x_0)$, that would mean, that
$$\forall r>0~ \exists x\in B_r(x_0):f(x) \leq 0$$
We can then define a sequence $(x_n)_n$ with $x_n\in B_{\frac{1}{n}}(x_0)$ s.t. $f(x_n) \leq 0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Obviously $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n = x_0$, but that implies, that
$$
0< f(x_0) = f(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(x_n)\leq 0
$$
which is a contradiction.